# Why does a pointer returned from strtok() cause a segmentation fault when passed to printf()?

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

```
int i = 0;
while(fgets(lineStr, sizeof(lineStr), pFile)!=NULL){
    puts(lineStr);
    pch = strtok (lineStr, delim);
    while(pch != NULL){
        printf("%s\n",pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL,delim);
    }
}
```

Overview: I'm trying to write a miniature version of grep (aka find the number of occurrences of a word in a text file). The entire code http://pastebin.com/VzTJkLK3

Problem: I'm trying to use strtok to tokenize an array of characters representing a line of text. I noticed using gdb that I get a segmentation fault like

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   __strlen_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strlen.S:31
>   31    ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strlen.S: No such file or directory.

Any hints or links to some more documentation is appreciated.

PS: I was told that using strtok is not a *good* programming practice - I'm a noob in C btw. What alternative would you recommend?

Comment: The problem with strtok is that you can only do one loop at a time per thread. The recommended alternative is `strtok_r` that uses an additional parameter instead of a "global" variable, but it's not in the C standard (I think it's included in the POSIX standard though, so as long as you're on *n*x you can use it without a problem).

Comment: I see nothing in your code sample that could cause a segfault, as long as `lineStr` is a valid buffer, `delim` a valid string and `pFile` a valid input stream.

Comment: lineString is a 256-byte array initialised on line 7 http://pastebin.com/VzTJkLK3

Comment: I do see a problem on the pastebin, but it would fail long before the loop: Your code opens the file in `argv[2]` *before* it checks `argc`...

Comment: Your sample doesn't include `<string.h>`, which is where `strtok()` is declared. (as well as `strlen()`). If this code is identical to yours, you need to `#include <string.h>`, and if it then-works, I'll explain why after you report back. Also, pick a language. This doesn't *look* like C++ code at all, and if it isn't intended to be, that language-tag should be removed.

Comment: including the string.h library solved it. Thanks @WhozCraig - I need new glasses :)

Comment: Do you want to know *why* ? I'll write it up as an answer if so.

Comment: @WhozCraig I do. Please do it.

Comment: I also want to know why. @FilipeGonçalves small world... I'm currently studying at IST - Alameda and Taguspark

Comment: I guess the moral of this story is not to ignore compiler warnings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code doesn't include `string.h` for including the prototypes of both `strlen()` and `strtok()`. The resulting behaviour is an interesting "feature" provided for legacy C compilation; the *implicit declaration*.

In C, if you don't declare a proper prototype (or the actual function isn't implemented) *before* its usage in a translation unit, the compiler will dutifully generate one for you, with a default return value type of `int`. This can often be a huge problem, and any decent compiler worth its salt will at least give you a warning about it, something to the effect of "Warning implicit declaration of function "foo" returns `int`"

So why is that such a bummer? Well, without including `string.h`, the compiler assumes the two functions you're using, `strlen()` and `strtok()`, look like this:

```
int strlen();
int strtok();
```

This declares two function prototypes, both returning `int` and accepting zero-or-more parameters. Another "helpful" feature of C for invoking such functions is allowing you to pass *anything* you want to these as arguments. The compiler will happily push them on the stack by-value:

```
int n = strlen(str); // pushes char* on the stack, then makes the call.
```

and similar, but not quite the same:

```
char *p = strtok(str, delim); // pushes two char* on the stack
```

So why did `strlen` seem to work, but `strtok` faulted? Well, because on your platform, `int` (the implied return type of your undeclared `strtok()` function) is not the same byte-size as `char*`, the place you're storing said-return value. In all likelihood you're on a 64-bit platform and `int` is 32bits, but pointers are 64-bit.

Therefore, only *half* the pointer is being saved, the other half (32bits) is not retained. thus the returned pointer is invalid and therefore kerboom.

The reason `strlen` appears to work is only because the value returned as an `int`' "fits" into your result variable. I.e. the function actually returned (in its `return` statement) a 64-bit int, but the caller-side (your code) only saved the "bottom" half. The value in the bottom half was sufficient to accurately reflect the length (the top half was `0`). Were the string enormous and requiring more than 32-bits to represent its length the same problem would have arisen. (and note, and that point you would have had other issues, like how did you get a contiguous 4gB string into your process address space).

Note: Closely related to this is the *main* reason you **never** cast the result of `malloc()` in C programs. A hard cast hides the warnings that will be emitted from this. It is also best-evidence it is good practice to always have pedantic warning levels enabled and turn on warnings-as-errors. In doing so things like this won't pass compilation and will be quickly discovered.

Comment: Excellent answer. Heed the warnings from the compiler.

Comment: +1 For the great answer. When I tested his code on my system, there was no segfault, it was really mysterious. Now I understand - my platform is 32 bits.